# Fixed field with non-normal subgroup and Galois property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Furthermore, let $g \in G$ and $M = L^{\langle g \rangle}$.

I know that $\langle g \rangle$ does not always have to be a normal subgroup of $G$ in general, and therefore $M/K$ does not have to be Galois. But is it still correct that $L/M$ is Galois even if $\langle g \rangle$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$? I expect $\operatorname{Gal}(L/M) = \langle g \rangle$ but I am not so sure about it.

If someone could confirm or object, that would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

$L/M$ is separable and normal (the $K$-minimal polynomials split completely in $L$ thus so do the $M$-minimal polynomials), therefore $L/M$ is Galois.

If you know the primitive element theorem then $L=K(a)$,

$Gal(L/M)$ is a subgroup of $Gal(L/K)$,

It is generated by $g$ because $a$ is a root of $f=\prod_{j=1}^{|\langle g\rangle|} (x-g^j(a))\in M[x]$,

An element of $Gal(L/K)$ is determined by where it sends $a$.

Any $h \not \in \langle g \rangle$ is not permuting the root of $f$ thus $h$ is not acting trivially on its coefficients, ie.  $h$ is not leaving $M$ fixed.